# Why Isn't Docker Build Caching?

Tags: docker

I have the following build command:

```
docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8 -t docker.io/bacalhauproject/log-processor:v0.2 .
```

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM debian:bullseye

RUN apt-get clean -y && apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y curl gnupg python3 python3-pip lsb-release gnupg wget unzip

# Install Google Cloud SDK and gsutil
RUN echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/releases/download/v0.7.1/duckdb_cli-linux-amd64.zip \
    && unzip duckdb_cli-linux-amd64.zip -d /usr/local/bin \
    && rm duckdb_cli-linux-amd64.zip

RUN pip3 install duckdb requests google-cloud-storage

WORKDIR /

COPY ./process.py /process.py
```

When I run it, it starts rebuilding with the 2nd line:

```
RUN apt-get clean -y && apt-get update -y
```

I get that this is a nondeterministic step - is there a way to force caching until I tell it not to?

Comment: Docker (in general, without speaking to buildkit) _does_ cache even nondeterministic steps. (This makes it deeply unreliable, and is part of why I advise against its use, but...)

Comment: ...that said, in the case of buildkit/buildx, have you looked at `--cache-from` and `--cache-to`? Even `--cache-to type=inline` is _something_. (Also see `--build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1`)

Comment: weirddddd - so then why isn't it caching? i'll look into --cache-from/to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker team helpfully provided the response. It was due to a GC setting:

```bash
# for no limit
docker buildx create --buildkitd-flags '--oci-worker-gc=false'
```

or

```bash
# for a simple 50GB gap
docker buildx create --buildkitd-flags '--oci-worker-gc-keepstorage=50000'
```